# how to get value in react datepicker format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker react js component, which is in the form of yyyy-MM-dd, but why does it invalid time value when I only use the data

```
const date = moment().format("yyyy-MM-dd");

class Register extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      BIRTH_OF_DATE:date
    }
  }

  render(){
   return(
     <DatePicker
      showPopperArrow={false}
      selected={this.state.BIRTH_OF_DATE}
      onChange={(newDate) => this.setState({BIRTH_OF_DATE:newDate})}
    />
   )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uset the `dateFormat` prop, but in this case that won't work because the format is wrong:

```
moment().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
"yyyy-01-Th"
```

This would be the correct form

```
 moment().format('YYYY-MM-dd')
    "2020-01-Th"
```

And then try:

```
 <DatePicker
  showPopperArrow={false}
  selected={this.state.BIRTH_OF_DATE}
  onChange={(newDate) => this.setState({BIRTH_OF_DATE:newDate})}
  dateFromat='YYYY-MM-dd' />
```

EDIT:

```
class Register extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      BIRTH_OF_DATE: moment().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    }
  }

  render(){
   return(
     <DatePicker
      showPopperArrow={false}
      selected={this.state.BIRTH_OF_DATE}
      onChange={(newDate) => this.setState({BIRTH_OF_DATE: moment(newDate).format("yyyy-MM-dd")})}
    />
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: I've done it and it works, but how do I change to the format yyyy-mm-dd?
before that I console.log the results are like this Sun Jan 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time),
what I want to get should be like this 2020-01-16 thanks very much

Comment: @MuhamadRahmatSetiawan - I realize I'm late to the party but why not use the `dateFormat` prop that is baked into `react-datepicker`. Not to mention you could do away with the over-bloated `momentjs` all together.

`dateFormat={"yyyy/MM/dd"}`

Answer (score 0):

You must set `onchange={this.handleOnchange}` and handle in function `handleOnchange`, You cannot `setState` on `render()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify a bit more about the issue you are facing. Assuming you are using `react-datepicker` package, I think I have found what went wrong.

[Here is the list of props of react-datepicker.](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md)  In this it is said that the `selected` prop should be a `Date` object. You are using a `moment` object, and that should be the problem. My advice is, use `Date` object first, and later change the output to whatever format you want it to be. Hope what I'm talking about is the issue you are facing, and my answer helps!

Also, if I'm understanding it right, you need the output to be in a said format. For that you can use the `dateFormat` prop, and give in the correct date format you want to use. Check on how the correct format of dates are given (`moment.js` documentation is a good place to look into), for example: `mm` and `MM` are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DatePicker
   selected={props.date}
   onChange={date => setDate(date)}
   customInput={ <ButtonInput /> }
/>
```

-------- Button Input ---------

```
// convert mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy
    const formatDate = (tgl) => {
        var temp = tgl.split('/');
    
        return (temp[1] + '/' + temp[0] + '/' + temp[2]);
    }
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
    const ButtonInputFR = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <Button outline
            onClick={props.onClick}
            ref={ref}
        >
            <i className="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o mr-1" />
            { formatDate(props.value) }
        </Button>
    ));
    
    ButtonInputFR.propTypes = {
        onClick: PropTypes.func,
        value: PropTypes.string
    }
    
    export { ButtonInputFR as ButtonInput };
```